# Error while installing Sitecore 10.2, Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

```
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sul6xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\Sitecore.MAEngine.exe`

Starting Marketing Automation Engine... 2022-06-21 10:20:10 ERR Error
initializing XConnect client. System.AggregateException: One or more
errors occurred. --->
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred
while sending the request. --->
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was
canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task
was canceled.    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
task)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.<InitializeAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.XConnect.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions.InitializeXConnectClientConfiguration(IServiceProvider
provider, XConnectClientConfiguration config)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: An error occurred
while sending the request. --->
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was
canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task
was canceled.    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
task)    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at Polly.Policy`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__48.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
task)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.<InitializeAsync>d__34.MoveNext()<---
ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not
been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.  
at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
at
Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass33_0.<UseServiceDecorator>b__1(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite
transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite
enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider
provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite
singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
callSite, TArgument argument)    at
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
scope)    at
 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider
provider)   at
 Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
at
 Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.RunAsConsoleApp(Boolean
interactive)
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue recently. 2 solutions I can suggest -

1. `Disable TLS 1.3` over TCP for xconnect. Rerun the installation script or disable this as soon as the xconnect bindings are setup by script during installation. for reference - https://sandeeppote.com/2021/11/14/step-by-step-guide-to-install-sitecore-xp-10-2-using-sif-on-windows-11/

[image]

2. After applying the above changes still I faced the issue so I `uninstall WAC`. After this, I started the installation again and it was successful.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav! I can confirm disabling TLS 1.3 is fixing the MarketingAutomataion service. I can start it manually now.

Comment: Please accept my answer if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot see any button to accept the answer

Comment: You can see it on the top left-hand side of my answer, just below the upvote downvote button.

Comment: nope, button is missing for me

Comment: @markcassidy could you please help here?

Comment: @nullcanvas you would see a right tick, just need to click on it.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a very old thread, and I could care less about up-votes and down-votes. But I need to share what worked for me. I needed to adjust the xConnect web app TLS binding to what is seen in the image attached. May it help you also.

[image]